# How to get text between 2 specific lines - Python

Tags: python

I have a big text, I have split it into lines.
Let's say the text is 100 lines
I want to get whatever is between line 30 and line 60
How do I do that?

Comment: Via list indices: `lines[30:60]`

Comment: Please post a sample of your text.

Answer (score 0):

With lists in python, you can chose what part of a list with the [x:y].

For example let's say you have a list

```
list = [0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5]
```

If you only want the part of the list contained between 1 and 4 you can type
`list[1:4]` and it will return you `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm got it right, your question is quite related to this: [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

You could do:

```
with open("file.txt") as file_in:
    lines = []
    for line in file_in:
        lines.append(line)
```

or simply:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

and work with the lines you would like to, according to index of lines created. Something like:

```
sub_text = lines[30:60]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lines are seperated by new lines, you can use the .split method to turn your long String into a list, and then get everything from index 29 to 59 using a for loop.

Here's an example:

```
seperatedText = longString.split("\\n")
for i in range 30:
   print(seperatedText[i + 29])
```

Of course you can also put the output into a second list by using the .append method or whatever you want.

I hope I could help you, and I'd really appreciate an upvote or an approve for my reputation :)